# Elasticsearch Query NOT searching in the specified fields

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, query-string, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I am struggling with an elasticsearch query. In the fields option, we have specified '*' which means it should look in all fields as well as given the higher weights to a few fields. But it isn't working as it should.
This query was written by my colleague, it'd be great if you could explain it as well as point out the solution. Here's my query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "Atoms for Peace",
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "flags": "PREFIX|PHRASE|NOT|AND|OR|FUZZY|WHITESPACE",
            "fields": [
              "*",
              "systemNumber^5",
              "global_search",
              "objectType^2",
              "partTypes.text",
              "partTypes.id",
              "gs_am_people^2",
              "gs_am_person^2",
              "gs_am_org^2",
              "gs_title^2",
              "_currentLocation.displayName",
              "briefDescription",
              "physicalDescription",
              "summaryDescription",
              "_flatPersonsNameId",
              "_flatPeoplesNameId",
              "_flatOrganisationsNameId",
              "_primaryDate",
              "_primaryDateEarliest",
              "_primaryDateLatest"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is not working in above query?

Comment: The query 'Atoms for Peace' exist in the title of a record but this query shows zero result although we have specified 'gs_title' with a weight of 2. And it also happens for other searched queries where they are present in the data but this query returns zero result or inaccurate result.

Comment: Can you add your mapping and sample document which contains "Atoms for Peace" to recreate it.  In my view your query should work fine

Comment: Mapping of the index is quite long, should I just add it in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is fine but it will not work on field with "nested" data type.

From [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

> Searching across all eligible fields does not include nested documents. Use a nested query to search those documents.

You need to use [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1, 
      "should": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "Atoms for Peace",
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "flags": "PREFIX|PHRASE|NOT|AND|OR|FUZZY|WHITESPACE",
            "fields": [
              "*",
              "systemNumber^5",
              "global_search",
              "objectType^2",
              "partTypes.text",
              "partTypes.id",
              "gs_am_people^2",
              "gs_am_person^2",
              "gs_am_org^2",
              "gs_title^2",
              "_currentLocation.displayName",
              "briefDescription",
              "physicalDescription",
              "summaryDescription",
              "_flatPersonsNameId",
              "_flatPeoplesNameId",
              "_flatOrganisationsNameId",
              "_primaryDate",
              "_primaryDateEarliest",
              "_primaryDateLatest"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "record",
            "query": {
              "simple_query_string": {
                "query": "Atoms for Peace",
                "default_operator": "AND",
                "flags": "PREFIX|PHRASE|NOT|AND|OR|FUZZY|WHITESPACE",
                "fields": [
                  "*"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The query failed with this exception
"reason" : "failed to create query: [nested] failed to find nested object under path [records]"
'Record' is just added in the API but not in the mapping itself. We do have a mix of fields with few nested fields. So is there any way to give a path to an index like you used 'records'?

Comment: @sheharbano i have modified query . Can you try it. Your field name is record, i was using records

Comment: For fields which are not of type nested, your query is fine and should give result. Nested data type is a special case in elasticsearch which needs use of nested queries. Separate nested queries are needed for separate nested fields . Another option is to use copy_to which will copy all data in a single sentence in a single field. To use it changes will be needed in mapping and reindexing of data and keywords will be searched across of all fields